# Quintus error "has no method animations"

Tags: javascript, html

Please help..I just can't figure out what makes the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object
>
> ```
> function (selector,scope,options) {   
>      return Q.select(selector,scope,options);   
> }
> ```
>
> has no method 'animations'

My code:

```
var Q = Quintus()
.include('Sprites', 'Anim')
.setup({width: 800, height: 480});

Q.Sprite.extend('Player', {
init: function(p){
    this._super(p, {
        sprite: 'player',
        sheet: 'player',
        x: Q.el.width/2,
        y: Q.el.height-60,
        type: Q.SPRITE_FRIENDLY,
        speed: 10
    });

    this.add('animation');
    this.play('default');
}
 });

Q.load(['spacebackground.png','spaceship2.png','player.json'], function(){
Q.compileSheets('spaceship2.png', 'player.json');

Q.animations('player', {default: {frames: [0,1,2,3], rate: 1/4}});

var bg = new Q.Sprite({asset: 'spacebackground.png', x: Q.el.width/2,
        y: Q.el.height/2, type: Q.SPRITE_NONE});
var player = new Q.Player();

Q.gameLoop(function(dt){
    Q.clear();
    bg.render(Q.ctx);
    player.update(dt);
    player.render(Q.ctx);
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

i bet that 50% of the ppl did that mistake, Quintus has some non-sence syntax sometimes, check this line:

```
.include('Sprites', 'Anim')
```

its should be 1 argument string:

```
.include('Sprites, Anim')
```

my mistake was that i putted the list of modules in array ! how stupid of me !

Comment: Im using the same tutorial and getting an error of 'this.play is not a function'

Comment: my mistake was calling - this.add('animations'); instead of - this.add('animation');